# Prevent Chrome from selecting everything when drawing outside of a canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, canvas

I'm making a little painting app using `canvas` and when drawing in the canvas everything is fine, but as soon as the user leaves the bounds of the canvas everything on the page is selected.

This doesn't happen in Firefox. I've showed the app so far to a couple people and every single one of them have mentioned how annoying it is. I've read around and apparently I could put

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

on every single div on the page but that seems like overkill. Also, I users to be able to select things on the page. It works perfectly in Firefox and doesn't select anything when leaving the canvas but for some reason in Chrome when drawing in the canvas the cursor changes to the selection cursor while drawing and upon leaving the canvas with left mouse button still held down everything gets selected.

Is this possible to fix?

Comment: Can't help much without seeing your code, but listen for the `mouseout` event and turn off your selection process. Mouseout fires when the mouse leave the bounds of the canvas element.

Comment: @markE: Yeah that appears to be the best solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `*` asterisk CSS selector like this:

```
* {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Another possible solution would be to apply the CSS rules to the `body` element, that might work equally well but it's untested.

You can set these CSS rules when the user focuses the `canvas` element and unset them if the user `blurs` the canvas (eg. sets focus on page).
Using this approach people can still select parts of the webpage but they won't select anything when they are in the canvas.

Comment: Oh yeah I guess I could just use javascript to toggle these rules on and off depending on if they're drawing. Ok I suppose I'll do that thanks. Kinda wish there was a better way though.